# How should I deal with online dependencies when running Rspec offline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, offline, rspec2

I would like to run RSpec to test my code both when I'm connected to the web and when I'm not.

Unfortunately there are some tests in the application which are dependent on having a live connection - email sending, Facebook integration etc.

Is there a best-practice way to create an online/offline testing environment or is this bad practice? Judging by how little I can find about this on the web I'm guessing the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in situations like that you would mock the parts of the code that connect outside your application. This allows you to test against the expected results from the service/system you are connecting to. It's also quicker to run tests.

There's a brief tutorial on mocking with rspec [here](https://wincent.com/blog/mocking-with-rspec) but I'm sure you can find plenty yourself.

For testing that emails get sent there are other approaches if you are sending through ActionMailer. There's a section on that in the [rails testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers).

EDIT (in response to comment):
You could put a method in `TestHelper` to only run tests when you are online. Something like:

```
def when_online
  if test_remote_connectivity
    yield
  else
    puts "Skipping test offline."
  end
end
```

Then you can call it like:

```
def test_facebook
  when_online do
    .....
  end
end
```

Not sure I entirely advocate it but it might do what you want!

Comment: Thanks Shadwell, very helpful. I'm already stubbing and mocking but I was wondering if there was any way I could do something along the lines of: 

if testRemoteConnectivity
  @online = true
else
  @online = false
end

pending @online do
 # remote dependency tests
end

I suspect I'm worrying too much about nothing but it would be nice to avoid red whilst disconnected

Comment: You could write a method to do that and only run tests that depend on being online when you were online (if you really want to!). Seems like more effort than mocking/stubbing things out in the long run (to me). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Nice - that was exactly the type of logic I was looking for. I agree with your assessment that it's probably not the right thing to do but it's nice to see how the code would be written if it were required

Answer (score 0):

You could use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) inside the tests/specs you don't want connecting to the remote resource.